# Calling d3.mouse on svg.node() after a timeout

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In the code snippet below, the second call to `d3.mouse` throws an error and I'm not sure why.

After running, just click on the rectangle.

```js
svg = d3.select('svg');

function clicked() {
  var node = svg.node();
  var xy1 = d3.mouse(node)
  alert([node, xy1]);
  setTimeout(function() {
    // alert(node) 
    // Uncomment above to check that node is well-defined
    var xy2 = d3.mouse(node);
    alert([xy1, xy2])
  }, 3000);
}
svg.on("click", clicked)
```

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Ultimately, my objective is to get the mouse coordinates relative to the SVG in a scenario like this where the function has been called via a `setTimeout` or similar delay. I whipped up this code since the `this` keyword doesn't work. That makes sense to me since `this` can change on function context. But it seems to me that once `node` has been set to `svg.node()`, that I should be able to call `d3.mouse` on it later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: you can't.

The problem here is not `this`, the problem here is the [event](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#event): there is no current event anymore when the code runs the `setTimeout`. You can see this by trying to log any event value in the `setTimeout`, you'll get a `null` for the event and a `undefined` for its properties:

```js
svg = d3.select('svg');

function clicked() {
  console.log("event is: " + d3.event)
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("event inside the setTimeout is: " + d3.event)
  }, 1000);
}
svg.on("click", clicked)
```

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

According to Mike Bostock, D3 creator:

> It is not supported to call d3.mouse when there is not a current user event.

In your case, you can use a [dispatch](https://github.com/d3/d3-dispatch), or you can try to store the `event` and passing it to your `setTimeout` callback.

However, since dispatches and events are a bit complicated, the simplest solution (although not a very wise one, regarding the use of the resources) is keeping track of the mouse position, and retrieving that position in the `setTimeout`.

Here is a demo:

```js
svg = d3.select('svg');

var pos;

function clicked() {
  var node = svg.node();
  var xy1 = d3.mouse(node)
  console.log(xy1);
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(pos)
  }, 3000)
}

svg.on("click", clicked);

svg.on("mousemove", function() {
  pos = d3.mouse(this)
})
```

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: So, we make a global variable `pos` to keep track of the position and just set that in the mousemove event. That is rather easy. I'll look into using a dispatch as well, though. Thanks!